# Do unimplement partial methods get replaced with null when used as a delegate parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, delegates, partial-methods

So i have 2 distinct methods.

one is a normal method

```
void DoSomething(delegate x)
{
     foreach(......)
     { x(); }
}
```

the other is a partial but unimplemented one

```
partial void DoWorkInForEach();
```

when i call my first method like this

```
DoSomething(DoWorkInForEach);
```

what will happen, will the delegate parameter be null, will my entire method call be deleted?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: Its not that i would not try it. I am on the road and thinking about it, and i cant use the pc while riding a bus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=7029):

> **10.2.7 Partial methods**
>
> [...]
>
> If a defining declaration but not an implementing declaration is given
> for a partial method M, the following restrictions apply:
>
> • **It is a compile-time error to create a delegate to method (§7.6.10.5).**
>
> • It is
> a compile-time error to refer to M inside an anonymous function that
> is converted to an expression tree type (§6.5.2).
>
> • Expressions
> occurring as part of an invocation of M do not affect the definite
> assignment state (§5.3), which can potentially lead to compile-time
> errors.
>
> • M cannot be the entry point for an application (§3.1).

If required, you can use a lambda here instead of a method-group, which would essentially give you a no-op delegate:

```
DoSomething(() => DoWorkInForEach());
```

Answer (score 1):

### Theory

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx):

> You can make a delegate to a partial method that has been defined and implemented, but not to a partial method that has only been defined.

And also [C# Language Specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552):

> If a defining declaration but not an implementing declaration is given for a partial method M, the following restrictions apply:
>   It is a compile-time error to create a delegate to method (§7.6.10.5).

---

### Example

The below is **correct**:

```
partial class Foo
{
    partial void Method();

    Foo()
    {
        Action action = new Action(Method);
    }
}

partial class Foo
{
    partial void Method()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And the following will throw a **compilation error**:

> Cannot create delegate from method 'Test.Foo.Method()' because it is a partial method without an implementing declaration

```
partial class Foo
{
    partial void Method();

    Foo()
    {
        Action action = new Action(Method); // Compilation error
    }
}
```